# LinkedIn API: get r_basicprofile using URL/vanityName

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I'm new to LinkedIn API.
Is there any way to retrieve `r_basicprofile` using v1 API?

I'm using Python and my GET url is:

```
'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?url=%s&oauth2_access_token=%s&format=json' %(v_member_url,v_access_token)
```

I get only my profile no matter what I put in `v_member_url`.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/%s&oauth2_access_token=%s&format=json' %(v_member_url,v_access_token)
```

try this

the `~` symbol stands for yourself.
this should be replaced with the personID

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/[PERSONID]&oauth2_access_token=[TOKEN]&format=json
```

Comment: Thank you, I searched more this issue and looks like the v2 is what I need. I will apply for partnership and use v2